# Why does RBD snap id start from 4?

Tags: snapshot, ceph, librbd

I'm a newbee Ceph developer, and recenlty reading code of snapshots. From
pg_pool_t::add_unmanaged_snap, **it's obvious that the first RBD snapshot id should
start from 2, but in reality, it starts from 4**, I wonder whether there are some organisms
in RBD snap, which increments snap_seq, could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Below is
the code of **pg_pool_t::add_unmanaged_snap**.

```
void pg_pool_t::add_unmanaged_snap(uint64_t& snapid)
{
  ceph_assert(!is_pool_snaps_mode());
  if (snap_seq == 0) {
    // kludge for pre-mimic tracking of pool vs selfmanaged snaps.  after
    // mimic this field is not decoded but our flag is set; pre-mimic, we
    // have a non-empty removed_snaps to signifiy a non-pool-snaps pool.
    removed_snaps.insert(snapid_t(1));
    snap_seq = 1;
  }
  flags |= FLAG_SELFMANAGED_SNAPS;
  snapid = snap_seq = snap_seq + 1;
}
```

Following screenshot is the process of rbd snapshot creation on a totally new rbd pool. Obviously, snapshot id here starts from 4

rbd snapshot creation on a totally new rbd pool

[image]

Comment: Can you show where you saw that it starts with 4? Did you already create and remove snapshots?

Comment: @eblock Yes, I've created snapshots in new rbd pool, and snap id starts from 4. Later I'll update a screenshot of rbd snap creation

Comment: No I mean did you create and delete snapshots before looking into the snap_id? Or was it a fresh pool with brand new snapshots?

Comment: @eblock It was a fresh pool with brand new snapshots, I've uploaded the whole process of creating new rbd pool and creating snapshots, maybe you could check in the figure

Comment: You are right, I could reproduce it. If you run `ceph osd pool ls detail` you will see that the pool already has a `removed snaps` entry: `pool 4 'iscsi-images' replicated size 3 min_size 2 crush_rule 0 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 128 pgp_num 128 last_change 166 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0 application rbd
        removed_snaps [1~3]`
But I don't know why there are already 3 removed snaps, to be honest. As soon as you create the rbd image there are 3 removed snapshots visible. I've never thought about that.

Comment: @eblock I wonder maybe there's some initialization process for ceph to create and delete a snapshot itself. Well, from the code I post, you could know that the first snapshot id should be 2.  ```if (snap_seq == 0) snap_seq = 1; snapid = snap_seq = snap_seq + 1;``` Also, from the code of ```pg_pool_t::remove_unmanaged_snap()```, we could know that snap_seq++ in removing process. So I guess that first ceph create a snap, snap_seq = 0 -> 1 -> 2, and remove it , snap_seq = 2 -> 3. When we create our own snap, snap_seq = 3 -> 4